# Ruby Geocoder: database query vs lookup

Tags: ruby, google-maps-api-3, rails-geocoder

I'm using the Ruby Geocoder gem and have a simple question.

If I fetch lat / lon coordinates on the client via javascript + Google Maps, then save them to my DB, how do methods like .near() and .nearbys() work thereafter? Are these strictly postgres queries or is a remote lookup being done?

I want to avoid the Google Maps API query limit, which is why I'm doing it like this. Basically, I never want my backend to call the API, I just want the client to send address + the corresponding fetched coordinates, and use this gem for database-only local queries.

Is that basically how this gem can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source, they should do only database calls. As much as I could see, you can do remote calls only through Geocoder::Query.

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb#L43
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb#L119

Answer (score 0):

That kind of queries (near and nearbys) are usually included as database features.  For example,  Mongodb include them. You should look in the documentation of your database.

You don't need geocoder gem for this.  Geocoder is used to interact with apis like Google maps or to do some common tasks not included on the database.